# Doubt with ethereum-input-data-decoder when decoding a variable uint256

Tags: web3js, nodejs, bignumber

the input data of the variable uint256 is "22092018" but when using ethereum-input-data-decoder I return "BN: 15118f2". Instead of getting "BN: 15118f2" with the decoder, have the original value of the transaction data entry "22092018".

[image]

Code:

```
const InputDataDecoder = require('ethereum-input-data-decoder');
const decoder = new InputDataDecoder(`${__dirname}/abi.json`);

const data = `0x070ec83b000000000000000000000.......;

const result = decoder.decodeData(data);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't fully understand the question but I think this might help.

JavaScript has no type for a 256-bit integer so web3.js includes the `bignumber.js` library.

Web3.js 1.0: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html?highlight=bignumber#bn

Web3.js 0.x: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js

To avoid loss of precision, cast JavaScript variables as bigNumbers and perform all math with the bigNumber implementation. Convert to strings or regular integers for interactions with humans.

Try your BN `variable.toString();`

More documentation on bigNumber itself: https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also 22092018 in hexadecimal is `1511f82` that is inside BN.